# pandas date-time format VS google sheets date format

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, data-science

I have a column in my dataset that looks like this:

```
date  
41245.0  
41701.0  
36361.0
```

I need to convert it into a date-format. When I try it in Python using this:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

My results are like this:

```
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000041701
4   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000042226
5   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000039031
```

These years seem quite odd. However, when I open the my dataset(as an excel sheet) on Google Drive/Sheets, select the column, and format it using the "date" or "date-time" format, the results are quite different.

```
12/2/2012
3/3/2014
7/20/1999
```

My results should be something like this. However, currently I am getting weird values. Similarly, the results on Microsoft Excel were also slightly different. Why are the dates different? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is days but the origin is 1900-01-01 not the default 1970-01-01

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date,unit='d',origin='1900-01-01')
Out[205]: 
0   2012-12-04
1   2014-03-05
2   1999-07-22
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: This works but could you explain this origin thing? I don't get much from the documentation. Will I always need to set this while using linux?

Comment: @x89 origin is more like date start, in pandas when we pass unit days , the origina is default to 1970-01-01 (Date= origin + days)