# Google Sheets date to Pandas datetime unexpected offset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, google-sheets

### Problem

I'm trying to accurately represent a date from Google Sheets in a DataFrame. I know that the "base" dates in Google Sheets are integers [added to the date since 1/1/1900](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969). Testing this is clear: I have a Sheet with the date `5/2/2019`. Using the Python API, I download this Sheet with the parameter `valueRenderOption='UNFORMATTED_VALUE'` to ensure I'm getting raw values, and do a simple conversion to a DataFrame. The value shows up as `43587`, and if I put that back into a Sheet and set the format to date, it appears as `5/2/2019`. Sanity check complete.

The problem arises when I try to convert that date in the DataFrame to an actual datetime: it shows up as offset by two days, and I'm not sure why.

### Attempts

In a DataFrame `df`, with datetime column `timestamp`, I do the following:

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='d', origin='1900-01-01')
```

and I get a date of `2019-05-04`, which is two days later than I would expect. I searched for this on SO and [found a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63105961/pandas-date-time-format-vs-google-sheets-date-format), but the accepted answer actually contains the exact same problem (albeit no mention of it): a two day offset.

This can be "solved" by setting the origin two days back, to `1899-12-30`, though that feels almost like a cover, and not necessarily fixing the underlying issue (and could perhaps leads to further date inconsistencies down the road as more time has passed?).

Here's code for a toy DataFrame so that you don't have to type it out, if you want to experiment:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'timestamp': 43587}])
```

### Question

I imagine this is on the Pandas side of things, but I'm not sure. Some internal conversion that happens differently than how they do it at Google? Does anyone have an idea of what's at play here, and if setting the origin date two days earlier is *actually* a solution?

Comment: It seems that the difference is not present for every period: setting `df = pd.DataFrame([{'timestamp': 0}])` actuallly sets the date to 1901-01-01, which is what is expected.

Comment: Yeah, that's my worry! That there's some leap-something going on, maybe? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been banging my head against this as well, and think that I finally figured it out. While for the Date() function, Sheets uses `1900-1-1` as the base, for the date format and for the TO_DATE() function, the origin date is `1899-12-30`.

You can see this in Sheets by either

- entering `0` in a cell, and then formatting to a date → `12/30/1899`
- entering `=TO_DATE(0)`, which will result in `12/30/1899`

One origin story for this odd choice is here in a very old [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1eef5fe-ef5e-4ab6-9d92-0998d3fa6e14/what-is-story-behind-december-30-1899-as-base-date?forum=accessdev) forum. I have no idea of its veracity.

At any rate, that explains the two-day discrepancy and then the solution becomes

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='d', origin='1899-12-30')
```

which worked for me.